# Adding jinja2 template code to javascript innerHTML

Tags: javascript, python, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am trying to get javascript to insert a flask-wtf form into a div as such.

```
var element = 'content'
var addElement = `{{ form.${element}(class="") }}`

var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.innerHTML = addElement;
```

Javascript displays my *addElement* as a string on my website instead of interpreting it to a form. I suspect this is because of the jinja2 syntax in there. How do i get it to display as a form?

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the javascript code with `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}`

```
{% raw %}
var element = 'content'
var addElement = `{{ form.${element}(class="") }}`

var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.innerHTML = addElement
{% endraw %}
```

Comment: Apologies, I'm not sure i made my question clear enough. My javascript is actually written in an external .js file. hardcoding the {{ form.${element}(class="") }} into a div in the html file creates the form as i require. But adding it through the javascript file prints out that exact syntax as a string in my website.

Comment: I have this same question. Did you find an answer @soby?